# get a field in a not direct related table i yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a table that have a relation like this :[image: My Relation]

Now i get a problem coz if you see, 
My work in table in deal_komisi.
But in my searchModel, I want my user can search based in table :  **item_Layanan.nama_item**

This is **My model**

```
class DealKomisi extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
        ...... //Common code

 /* Related to list_harga */
 /**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getListHarga() {
    return $this->hasOne(ListHarga::className(), ['id' => 'list_harga_id']);
}
```

So, in my DealKomisiSearch, I just use this :

```
public function search($params) {
    $query = DealKomisi::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'list_harga_id' => $this->list_harga_id,
        'komisi' => $this->komisi,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    ]);

    $query->joinWith('listHarga');

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'created_by', $this->created_by])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'updated_by', $this->updated_by])
    ;

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

What Should I do, **P.S**
I also created the **list_harga** model which is, the relation to **item_layanan ** is definite like this.

```
class ListHarga extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord


 public function getItemLayanan()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ItemLayanan::className(), ['id' => 'item_layanan_id']);
}
```

Please advise.
Any help it so appreciated